# É possível verificar se duas variáveis estão definidas de uma maneira mais fácil?

Tags: php

Eu recebo pelo formulário via POST os campos `sd` e `video`, precisando verificar se ambas estão definidas. Atualmente faço o seguinte:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['sd'])) {

    $sd = $_POST['sd'];

    if (isset($_POST['video'])) {

        // ...

    }

}
```

Tem como fazer essa verificação de forma mais simples?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**, para fazer um bom uso do site, favor fazer o [tour], para saber mais sobre o mesmo, acesse a [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `isset` aceita diversos parametros, assim:

```
if(isset($_POST['sd'], $_POST['video'])){

    $sd = $_POST['sd'];

    $vid = $_POST['video'];


    $sql = "UPDATE `player` SET `sd` = '$sd', `video` = '$vid' WHERE `id` = 3";
    $ssl = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $_SESSION['post'] = 'Configuração salva com sucesso!';
    header("Location: edit.php");

    exit();

}
```

Só pra constar, recomendo que use `mysqli_real_escape_string` para evitar SqlInjection, assim:

```
if(isset($_POST['sd'], $_POST['video'])){

    $sd = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['sd']);

    $vid = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['video']);


    $sql = "UPDATE `player` SET `sd` = '$sd', `video` = '$vid' WHERE `id` = 3";
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Pela sua Ajuda